# Efficient exponentials with small base

Tags: c, math

I need to perform a softmax operation. That is, given a sequence of `n` real values ranging from -inf to +inf, I turn them into probabilities by exponentianting each value and dividing for the sum of exponentials:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    p_x[i] = exp(x[i]) / sum_exp(x, n)
```

(don't take the code literally, I'm not summing up all `exp`'s every iteration!)

I'm having overflow problems when values go above 700 in some extreme cases (using 8-bytes doubles). I know I could use another base instead of e, however, I'm afraid calling `pow` will be much slower than `exp` (speed is critical for me).

What is the fastest way to solve this?

Comment: Don't be _afraid_ of `pow` being slower. _Benchmark it!_ If you can't measure, you can't improve.

Comment: If you're afraid of `pow`, how about `exp2`? It performs `2^x` instead of `e^x`.

Comment: I benchmarked `pow`, `exp` and `exp2` (which I didn't know). `exp` seems to be 40~50 times faster than `pow` and 6~7 than `exp2`. Well, that's already something.

Comment: 700 doesn't seem extreme compared to `+Inf`.  Can you restrict your domain further?

Comment: In fact, I found it easier and more efficient to subtract a constant value from every exponent. This way, the result is left unchanged. I only noticed later that using different bases will yield different probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Use each number as the 52-bit mantissa in a 64-bit floating point number. This is simply a matter of masking then casting.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  long long val = 1234567890;
  long long mval = val & ~0xfff0000000000000ULL;
  float fval = *((float*)&mval);
  printf("%f", fval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b^x = e^(x * ln b)
```

So using a smaller base `b` is equivalent to multiplying your values by `ln b` before applying `exp`, and dividing again at the end.